# PySNMP No Response Received Before Timeout--Even with Documentation Examples

Tags: timeout, snmp, pysnmp

I have installed PySNMP (version 4.4.6) and am attempting to call the following function (part of a larger class):

```
def walk(self):
    #Walks OID to scavenge for information.
    oids={}
    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData(self.cs),
                              UdpTransportTarget((self.device.split(".")[0], 161), timeout=60, retries=0),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity("1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.1.2.5.5"))):
        print((errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds))
```

and repeatedly receive the following output:

```
(RequestTimedOut('No SNMP response received before timeout',),
```

I have triple-checked to make sure that my community string, SNMP version, device name, port, and OID are correct.  I have altered the Transport timeout variable 60 seconds with no luck.  My first thought was that it might be a firewall issue, but then I tried to run the simple example included in the documentation:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public'),
       UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))

print(next(g))
```

And receive the exact same output.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?  Unfortunately I'm on a server with few admin rights, so I can't go digging through module files changing anything.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. For as long as you get the right hostname/IP out of `self.device.split(".")[0]`.

May be you are not getting response from your SNMP agent for one reason or the other. I'd try public SNMP agent:

```
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com 1.3.6
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux zeus 4.8.6.5-smp #2 SMP Sun Nov 13 14:58:11 CDT 2016 i686
...
```

To make sure you do not have connectivity/firewall problems. Consider trying `snmpwalk` against your local SNMP agent as well. If you can't have Net-SNMP installed, consider trying [snmpclitools](https://github.com/etingof/snmpclitools) for conducting this experiment.

Comment: Ah, it looks as if SNMP isn't configured on this server.  Thanks for the assist!